# Clues integrating jcart in Drupal 7

Tags: 7

jcart is a great shopping cart that uses a php class inside a jcart.php file. The cart is being displayed

```
<div id="jcart"><?php $jcart->display_cart();?></div>
```

I managed to create a module to list the product items and the form with 'add to cart' button, also to include the jcart.css and jcart.js inside everypage. The only thing I need to include more are:

1. the mymodule/jcart/jcart.php

I tried to include it in my header of html.tpl.php but I get an error while displaying `$jcart->display_cart()`. The error is:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function display_cart() on a non-object
>   in...

1. To add a class to the form: class

If there is someone could help I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the file itself, [`module_load_include`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/function/module_load_include/7) can help you with that. Then you need to instantiate the class, you should read the docs about jcart to figure out how to do that, but something like

```
 $jcart = new jCart($args);
```

This can be done in your theme, or ever better create block in your module than will display the cart and that will invoke `display_cart`.

Note I don't know anything about jcart, and as such the code is just an illustration.

Comment: Thank you, I included with function MY_MODULE_preprocess_html(&$vars) {

  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'shop'). '/jcart/jcart.php';
  include_once $path;
} the cart doesn't need instantiation it is already done in that file and I only displayed <div id="jcart" style="width:200px"><?php $jcart->display_cart();?></div> the cart but i got errors